# Should I create a separate table in DB for UserAddress helper class Java, Hibernate, Postgres?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, design-patterns

I am making a small restful service for user management. By assignment, the User is defined by the following values:

```
◦ First name 
◦ Last name 
◦ Date of birth 
◦ Login 
◦ Password 
◦ Input field “About me” 
◦ Address of residence (country, city, street, house, flat)
```

When designing, I paid attention to the address and thought that it would be wrong to write everything together in one address field and make a similar attribute in the database table, because then different filtering by addresses would become very inconvenient. Then I delimited the address field into 5 fields (those in brackets). However, having done so, I realized that my class, given the id field, has 13 fields, what, in my understanding, makes the class too overloaded and "wrong". Then I decided to make a separate class for the address and use it as a field for the user, namely:

```
@Entity
public class UserAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private int house;
    private int flat;

}
```

And having done so, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed, as a result of which I have the following questions:

1. Should I move 5 address fields into a separate class in UserAddres?
2. If so, is it worth to make this class Entity and creating table in the database for it?
3. Should I consider it like a complete class (create getters / setters, equals and hashcode, service layer, controller and repository layers)?
4. Will filtering users by address become even more complicated than it was originally?
5. What is the best way to deal with such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

1. Moving them into an extra table allows you to store more than 1 Address per user without redundancy of user data (like name).
2. Yes, because JPA / Hibernate will take care of PK/FK-Relationship using @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations.
3. Equals/Hashcode yes. Getters and Setters probably yes, depends on the way you handle this data. If you've got user input, e.g. via a GUI, you will need getters and setters. Somewhere you probably have to "fuse" address and user data to your Service's User data (the one going out).
   **Edit**: If an Address object is invalid without belonging to a User, then only being able to manipulate the Address-Object via its User-object can help your data consistency.
4. No. JPA offers convenient ways to join tables.
5. The best-practice regarding your Restful Service would be to have a mapper between your Entities (User + Address between DB and App) and your DTOs (User + Address, between App and 3rd Party).

Comment: I don't have a GUI, I do only a server side, but what abous controller and repository. Shold I make an oportunity to interact personaly with Address, or should it be reached only through the user.